# Margin of header is added to body (how to solve it ?)

Tags: css, margin, border-box

I try to solve this problem for hours ...
I tried a few tricks, some small hack, I also tried to add positions "relative, absolute...Etc", some "top", top add a invisible not fixed div behind the fixed and others, but I want the cleanest solution possible and to know WHY have I got this problem.

: I have a menu "fixed" to the top, and a header.
The header is behind the menu (normal), but **the problem is that when I add a margin to the header, it adds a margin to the body, while I want to add margin to the header INSIDE the body, just place the header under the menu without position:relative+top:Xpx.
And use "box-sizing: border-box" doesn't change anything**

***http://jsfiddle.net/WdNz4/***

```
<div id="menu">
</div>

<div id="header">
    test1(Success)<br>test2<br>test3(Lose)<br>test4<br>test5
</div>
```

(can't post my css, little bug, go to jsfiddle)

Thanx in advance for your help !

Comment: The phenomenon is called *margin collapse*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `top:0;` property to your `#menu`:

```
#menu {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    top:0; 
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WdNz4/4/

Comment: @GisbawerWinstol it  happens to everyone sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use float:left; this will set your block outside the body structure, so that way you can position it anyway you want.